# If $f:S\to \mathbb C$ is real valued function, then integral of $f$ over any contour in $S$ is real

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Is the statement true or false?

> Let $S\subseteq \mathbb C$ be a domain, $f:S\to \mathbb C$ be a real valued function on $S$. Then integral of $f$ over any contour in $S$ is a real number.

**My attempt**

If $f$ is analytic, I could conclude that f is a constant function using Cauchy Riemann equation. Then, integral over a closed contour will be zero. I tried to give counter examples also. None of them was working.

Comment: If $f(z)=1$ for $\Re z \geq 0$ and $0$ for $\Re z <0$ then the integral of $f$ over the unit circle is $2i$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.